# Android - ContextMenuInfo always null in dynamic LinearLayout

Tags: android

I started working on an app with some `fragments`. In one `fragment` I want to display data I receive via UDP in a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout`. The number of datasets is irregular. There should be a pop-up menu when I click on an entry for long.

What is working:
- receiving packets
- display them in the `ScrollView`.

What is not working:
- open a pop-up menu

Here the code:

```
public void updateList(final String received){
    received_parts_hash = received.split("#");
    // clear layout everytime a new string is received
    if(linearLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<received_parts_hash.length; i++){
        String[] received_parts = received_parts_hash[i].split(";");
        myTv = new TextView(getActivity());

        String myString = received_parts[0] + ", " + received_parts[1] + ", " + received_parts[2];
        myTv.setText(myString);


        linearLayout.addView(myTv);
        registerForContextMenu(myTv);
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId()==myTv.getId()) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        String information = received_parts_hash[info.position+1];
        String[] information_parts = information.split(";");
        menu.setHeaderTitle("info");
        menu.add(information_parts[3]);
        menu.add(information_parts[4]);
        menu.add(information_parts[5]);
    }
}
```

`onCreateContextMenu()` is called when I long click an item, but menuInfo is always null so the app crashes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A `LinearLayout` is not an `AdapterView`. There's not going to be an `AdapterContextMenuInfo` for those context menus. If you want the position, you could call `setTag(i)` on the `LinearLayout`s in the loop, and then `getTag()` on the `View` passed into `onCreateContextMenu()` to retrieve it. Alternatively, you could instead use a `ListView`, in which case you would get an `AdapterContextMenuInfo` there.

Comment: I had to call `setTag(i)` on `myTv` and make some minor changes. It now works like it should. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I misspoke. I meant to say `TextView`s. Well, glad you got it working. Cheers!